# Avro equivalent of Protocol Buffers 'oneof' type

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, avro

Wanted to know if there is any good Avro type or definition (or combination of) to simulate protobuf's "oneof" type. I didn't see an easy way to make a field optional, nor to restrict it to one selection of many.

If there's no good equivalent, how would you suggest trying to implement this with Avro?